# How do I make this Loop Backwards

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code prints numbers from 1 to 19, 2 to 18, 3 to 17 etc.

```
for i in range(1,20):
    for x in range(i,21-i):    
        print x,
```

How do I make it go backwards from 17 to 3, 18 to 2 until it reaches 19 to 1 ?

Comment: `range()` has a 3rd parameter, `step`, which determines how much to increment on each iteration. Set this to `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in function `reversed`:

```
for i in reversed(range(1, 20)):
    for x in reversed(range(i, 21-i)):    
        print x
```

Comment: This throws error `NameError: name 'reverse' is not defined` executed in IDLE python version 3

Comment: @Dev yes, my bad, it should be `reversed`

Answer (score 0):

if you use a negative number for 3rd argument of range() you can use backward loop
for example:

```
for i in range(20, 0, -1):
    print(i)
```

for your code you can simply do something like this:

```
for i in range(0, 20):
    for x in range(20 - i, i, -1):    
        print(x)
```

for more read this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop